# jQuery Select by ID with variable

Tags: jquery

I have some code that creates some span tags and each span has its own ID

```
counter1
counter2
counter4
```

by its name in the database.
Now I'm trying to reach the value of one of them. So, I tried something like this:

```
var id = // Any number that have a span.
var Counter = $("#counter" + id).val();
alert(Counter);
```

But, it's just showing "NaN"

Comment: You store the value in 'Counter', but try and alert some variable named 'likes'...?

Comment: You never define `likes` but you define `Counter`. is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry my bad, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Post the html for these spans you are trying to select. If by value you really mean you want to access inner html, use .html() instead of .val()

Comment: @Videron Could you provide us with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `.val()` to `.html()` to access the innerHtml of an html element. `.val()` selects the value of an html input element as detailed in the [API](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

```
var id = // Any number that have a span.
var Counter = $("#counter" + id).html();
alert(Counter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a `val()`ue of a `<span>`. You have to use `html()` or `text()`.

Answer (score 1):

Mmmmm try:

```
var Counter = $("#counter" + id).html();
```

or

```
var Counter = $("#counter" + id).text();
```

I´m dont sure, but maybe span dont have "value" attribute.